# Azure Load Testing: How to read the supportive CSV file from a storage account for the Azure Load Testing?

Tags: azure, azure-load-testing

I have created a test in Azure Load Testing using Azure CLI

> az group create --name sample-rg --location westus2
>
> az load create --name sample-resource --resource-group sample-rg
> --location westus2
>
> az load test create --test-id weather-multiple-cities
> --load-test-resource sample-resource --resource-group sample-rg --display-name "Weather-Multiple-Cities" --description "Test description" --test-plan "Weather App with CSV.jmx" --engine-instances
> 1 --env rps=2 count=1 --env rps=2 count=1
>
> az load test file upload --test-id weather-multiple-cities
> --load-test-resource sample-resource --resource-group sample-rg --path WeatherData.csv --file-type ADDITIONAL_ARTIFACTS --no-wait

[image]

However, I want to read the supportive CSV file from a storage account instead of storing it along with the Azure Load Testing. This will enable us to update the corresponding CSV externally without having to touch the Azure Load Testing resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible today.

As a workaround idea, you could build a simple pipeline, e.g. with a Logic App that listens to changes to your blob and updates the file with Azure Load Test when it changes.